# If all the eigenvalues of a self-adjoint operator $L$ are positive then $L$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $L$ be a self-adjoint operator on a finite dimensional vector space $X$ and assume all its eigenvalues are positive. Show that $L$ is positive definite.

I am reading up on the following proof but I don't follow one of the last steps. It goes like this:

> We can find an orthonormal basis for $X$ consisting of eigenvectors $v_i$ of $L$. Every $x \in X$ can be written as $\sum c_i v_i$. From here it follows that 
>   $$
> \big\langle L(x),\,x \big\rangle 
> = \left\langle L \left(\sum c_i v_i\right),\,\sum c_i v_i \right\rangle 
> = \left\langle \sum c_i \lambda_i v_i,\,\sum c_i v_i \right\rangle 
> = \sum \left\lvert c_i\right\rvert^2 \lambda_i >0.
> $$
>   So $L$ is positive definite.

- I don't follow why $\left\langle \sum c_i \lambda_i v_i,\,\sum c_i v_i \right\rangle = \sum \left\lvert c_i\right\rvert^2 \lambda_i$. What happens in this step?
- Why do they use an orthonormal basis instead of just an orthogonal basis?

Answer (score 4):

In that step, you expand using bilinearity of the inner product, obtaining

$$\sum_i \sum_j c_i \lambda_i c_j (v_i,v_j)$$

but by assumption $(v_i,v_j)=0$ unless $i=j$. (You can fill in the conjugates for the complex case yourself.) Also, $(v_i,v_i)=1$, again by assumption.

As for the orthonormality, it is often convenient to assume eigenvectors are unit. It usually makes no real difference, but if you don't do it then you often wind up normalizing further down the line anyway. Here it really wouldn't make much difference, there would just be a $\| v_i \|^2$ in the last sum if you didn't assume the $v_i$ were unit.

Comment: Missing a complex conjugate on $c_j$ (or perhaps $c_i$ depending on convention.  Unless you're working over $\mathbb R$, but then the notation $|c_i|^2$ seems a bit redundant :).

Comment: @ErickWong I mentioned that.

Comment: ah, sorry I missed that.